# Why would I get a lot of None.get exceptions while draining a streaming pipeline?

Tags: spotify-scio

I am running into issues where I have a streaming scio pipeline running on Dataflow that is deduplicating messages and performing some counting by key. When I try to drain the pipeline I get a large amount of `None.get` exceptions supposedly thrown in my deduplicate step (I am basing this assumption off the label I am observing in the stackdriver log).

We are currently running on scio version 0.7.0-beta1 and beam version 2.8.0. I have tried protecting as much as I can in my code from any potential Nones but this appears like it is occurring further down inside of the deduplicate step.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
"java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at com.spotify.scio.util.Functions$$anon$2.mergeAccumulators(Functions.scala:227)
    at com.spotify.scio.util.Functions$$anon$2.mergeAccumulators(Functions.scala:220)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateInternals$WindmillCombiningState.getAccum(WindmillStateInternals.java:958)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateInternals$WindmillCombiningState.read(WindmillStateInternals.java:920)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:202)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1226)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:965)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As you can see, this never really enters my code and I am unsure how I should go about finding this issue. Perhaps it has something to do with the "LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner"? Our allowed lateness is relatively large (3 days with windows being an hour long).

```
val input = PubsubIO.readStrings()
  .fromSubscription(subscription)
  .withTimestampAttribute("ts")
  .withName("Window messages")
    .withFixedWindows(
      duration = windowSize,
      options = WindowOptions(
        trigger = AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
          .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
            .plusDelayOf(earlyFiring))
          .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
            .plusDelayOf(lateFiring)),
        accumulationMode = ACCUMULATING_FIRED_PANES,
        allowedLateness = allowedLateness
      )
    )
  .withName(s"Deduplicate messages")
  .distinctBy[String](f = getId)

...
// I am being overly cautious here because I have been having
// so much trouble debugging this
def getId(message: Map[String, Any]): String = {
  message match {
    case null => {
     logger.warn("message is null when getting id")
      ""
    }
    case message => {
      message.get("id") match {
        case None => {
          logger.warn("id is null in message")
          ""
        }
        case id => id.get.toString
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am confused how I could possibly be getting a `None.get` here and why that would only occur when I am draining.

Can I have some advice on how I should go about debugging this error or where I should be looking?

Comment: Could be a bug. Can yo file an issue on https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues?

Comment: Hi! Yea I filed [1620](https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/1620). We have since changed how we interact with Beam so I have been unable to follow up with that issue. Where I left off was that I am pretty sure there is a bug in [mergeAccumulators](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/v0.7.0-beta1/scio-core/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/util/Functions.scala#L136) where it would sometimes return None's all the way up through the merges if enough SCollections were empty.